# Masonry not working for multiple widths

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, jquery-masonry, masonry

I'm new to masonry with angular. i have tried to get masonry working with angular up to a certain extend and im facing few issues with it right now. Below given link is what i have done so far and the following are the two issues facing:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div class="grid" masonry="true" column-width="460">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="item {{item.class}}">
            <div><h1>{{item.name}}</h1></div>
            <br /> <span>Age: {{item.age}}</span>
            <br /> <span>Company: {{item.company}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Link to jsfiddle for my solution](http://jsfiddle.net/67m2xqst/19/)

1. instance 1

[image]

When there is enough space the smaller brick does not get adjusted. E.g. After "Collin Alston" i need to have "Jasmine Rollins" and likewise. How would i accomadate this change? (see for image below as well)

[image]

2. instance 2

[image]

Why is it that "style" attribute gets applied to child elements? i need the style to be applied to "item w1 masonry-brick" and not child div's.

I had  in instance 1 and changed it to  for instance 2 to show the two problems im facing. Hope to get some answers to work my way out. Thank you in advance.

**Update 1:**

I managed to get masonry working with angular to this extend. Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/h5jfd1wm/38/

But still there are some empty spaces when i resize the window. It's like some bricks from the bottom can fill up those empty spaces. If you can help me out here.

Comment: There seems to be already a angular wrapper for masonry, would you care to use that? I've never used masonry, but briefly looking into it and your fiddle, your design seems off. It looks like you need to tell masonry that things have been appended. You should create a masonry-item directive that requires the masonry directive and use its controller to tell it that a child has been added.

Comment: In that case i will need to edit angular mansonry file right?

Comment: + how would i stop the adding of "Style" attribute for the child div's?

Comment: No you wouldn't need to modify angular masonry. You simply would have to hg-repeat on your new directive, something like so: http://jsfiddle.net/g30pbjf9/, although it doesn't work right now. And have the new directive tell the masonry that things have been added and masonry should handle the rest as it would in pure javacript. But maybe I'm missing the actual question.

Comment: But to stop the adding of the style, you can technically override the styling with your own in css, but I think you have a different problem here. Are you opposed to using a library that has already done this for you?

Comment: I can use the angular masonry library. I mean i have to because my app is running on angular. Unless i have a way of pluging it jquery masonry. With that the issue is i use ng-repeat and then jquery does not take care of the bricks after its added by angular.

Comment: I mean can you use a wrapper someone already wrote for masonry. With the wrapper you just provide the list of items to their directive and it just works. You can google angular masonry and find few GitHub that has done this for you. All you have to do is learn how to use their masonry directive

Comment: Check my update in the post. If you can help me out from here...

Comment: If it's not filling properly on resize you need to listen to resize and tell masonry to update itself.